# Use apache as a foward proxy and redirect all reques to a static page

Tags: apache, mod-rewrite, mod-proxy

I trying to set up Apache as proxy which will eventually rewrite requests for JavaScript files to a different codes base. I have Apache set up and acting as a proxy but no matter what I do it will not use the rewrite rule config is shown below.

Currently this is all ruining on my local machine.

```
<VirtualHost *:8000>
RewriteEngine on 
RewriteRule "(.*)" "http://127.0.0.1/test.html" [P]
DocumentRoot "c:/wamp/www/ipvproxy"
ServerName ipvproxy
ProxyRequests On
ProxyVia On
<Proxy *>
    Order deny,allow
    Deny from all
    Allow from 127.0.0.1
</Proxy>
```

Working Config

```
<VirtualHost aaa.bbb.ccc.ddd:8000>
   DocumentRoot "c:/wamp/www/"
   CustomLog "c:/wamp/logs/vhost.log" common
   ErrorLog "c:/wamp/logs/vhost_error.log"
   ProxyRequests On
   <Proxy *>
      Order deny,allow
      Deny from all
      Allow from all
   </Proxy>
   RewriteEngine on
   RewriteLog "c:/wamp/logs/rewrite2.log"
   RewriteLogLevel 9
   RewriteRule .* http://127.0.0.1/test.html
</VirtualHost>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It turns out the issue lay with the wampserver version I was using. Running  Wampserver 64 bit on Windown 7 64 bit has issues with mod_rewrite, changed to wampserver 32 bit and it all started to work.

Answer (score 0):

You should use reverse proxy.

Something like that:

```
<VirtualHost *:8000>
    DocumentRoot "c:/wamp/www/ipvproxy"
    ServerName ipvproxy

    ProxyPass / http://127.0.0.1/test.html
    ProxyPassReverse / http://127.0.0.1/test.html
</VirtualHost>
```

Then any request come to http://ipvproxy:8000 will be translated to http://127.0.0.1/test.html

More info [here](http://www.apachetutor.org/admin/reverseproxies) and [here](http://httpd.apache.org/docs/2.2/mod/mod_proxy.html)

Comment: I just wonder why you are using either a Proxy or reverse proxy for a loopback scenario like this.  Apache server will be acting as a proxy here: that is cascading get requests back it itself and then processing it again.  Would Redirect or Rewrite be lighter weight and therefore more appropriate for this scenario?

Comment: No joy what has me really confused is that I have `    RewriteLog "c:/wamp/logs/rewrite.log"
    RewriteLogLevel 9` and I see nothing in the logs as if it never looks at the rule

Comment: Yea it's a horrible thing I am trying to do. I am running a a web app on a jetty server on the local machine and need to eventually rewrite requests for certain javascript files to a different location (I can't alter the web app or jetty server). So I thought a way to do this would be set up a proxy and then rewrite the request for the certain files. @TerryE

Comment: @dead_zero, the rewrite log will stay empty unless to issue a `RewriteEngine on` and use `RewriteRule` directives.  Re proxy, I understand -- you are using Apache on localhost:8000 as a **reverse** proxy infront of your jetty server on localhost:80.